# Is every graph an edge-crossing graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-geometry, graph-drawing

Consider a [circular drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_layout) of a simple (in particular, loopless) graph $G$ in which edges are drawn as straight lines inside the circle. The *crossing graph* for such a drawing is the simple graph whose nodes correspond to the edges of $G$ and in which two nodes are adjacent if and only if the corresponding edges cross.

**Example.** The graph $G$ has four vertices (1–4) and three edges (a–c) where $a = 12$, $b = 13$, $c = 24$. In the circular drawing, $b$ and $c$ cross, so the crossing graph has three nodes and a single edge $bc$.

[image: Example of a graph drawing and its crossing graph]

Here are my questions:

1. Is every simple graph the crossing graph of some circular graph drawing?
2. If not, how does a counterexample look like?
3. If yes, how can such a graph drawing be constructed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such graphs are called "circle graphs" and if you search on that phrase you will find some literature. For example, some is around page 56 in [this book](http://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=bAGW1L84hRQC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=crossing%20chord%20graph&ots=R_jz3vps1w&sig=4AltkQYV2XfPqElucxnDO2o1c9E#v=onepage&q=%22circle%20graph%22&f=false).

Figure 2 in [this paper](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b91026/2008_02_24_OutOfDate/p435-gabor.pdf) shows a 7-vertex graph that is not a circle graph, but according to [OEIS:A156809](http://oeis.org/A156809) there are two with 6 vertices.

Answer (score 15):

The answer to 1 is **no**.  To see this, note that every edge-crossing graph is a [string graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_graph).  A *string graph* is a graph which is the intersection graph of arbitrary curves in the plane.  However, there are graphs which are not even string graphs.

One example of a graph which is not a string graph is $K_5$ with each edge subdivided once.
To see this, let $G$ be $K_5$ with each edge subdivided once and suppose that $\mathcal{S}$ is a string representation of $G$.  Let $S_1, \dots, S_5$ be the strings in $\mathcal{S}$ that correspond to the degree-4 vertices of $G$.  Since the degree-4 vertices are an independent set in $G$, these strings are pairwise disjoint.  Since the degree-2 vertices are also an independent set in $G$, by shrinking each of $S_1, \dots, S_5$ down to a point in $\mathcal{S}$, we get a planar drawing of $K_5$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

No, and you can see this from just a counting argument.

For determining which of the $ n $ chords of the circle intersect, it is enough to know the order of the $ 2n $ endpoints on the circle.  (You can assume that no two endpoints coincide.)  There are at most $ (2n)!/2^n $ such orders (the two endpoints of a chord aren't distinguishable).  On the other hand, there are exactly $ 2^{n(n-1)/2} $ simple graphs on $ n $ nodes.  The latter grows faster.

You can even get an explicit bound from this: there are more simple graphs on 16 nodes than arrangement of 13 chords in the circle, so at least one of those graphs can't be generated this way.